# MySQL: Delete from database when id first letters are numbers

Tags: mysql, delete-row

I am trying to delete a row from my database and the **aid** which is generated from an external API contains number.

For example this are the aid's:

```
16RYR3w
15LSPf1
10sLK3
5PlsKs
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
$uid = 1;
$aid = '15LSPf1';

DELETE FROM favorites WHERE uid='". $uid ."' AND aid LIKE '". $aid ."'
```

This doesn't work. What I'm I doing wrong? I dont have a choice of changing the id because the numbers are in a random order.

Comment: Can you use the string itself instead of the variable, and use the % character, eg DELETE FROM favorites WHERE uid = '1' and aid like '%15LSPf1%' ?

Comment: If you're dealing with an external API that generates values, a `DELETE` with a `LIKE` (done properly) may remove more than one record. For example, `DELETE ... WHERE aid LIKE '%15LSPf1%'` will delete rows where the `aid` is `'15LSPf1'`, `'X15LSPf1'`, `'15LSPf1MoreCharacters'`, etc.

Comment: Why are you using `LIKE` in `aid` col? Does your `aid` col contain more than the generated `aid`?

Comment: Is uid a numeric or a character column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you're looking for:

```
$aid = stripslashes($_GET['aid']);
$query="DELETE FROM favorites WHERE uid='". $uid ."' AND aid LIKE '%". $aid ."%'";
```

And note that `LIKE` is **only** 10x faster than `REGEXP`. More on the test can be found here: http://thingsilearn.wordpress.com/2008/02/28/mysql-query-speed-regexp-vs-like/

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to delete *any* rows where the first `aid` character is a numeral, use a regular expression:

```
DELETE FROM favorites WHERE uid=whatever AND aid RLIKE '^[0-9]'
```

The regular expression above checks for "beginning of string" (that's the `^`) followed by "any number" (that's the `[0-9]`).

Comment: I am looking to delete ONE specific row where aid = 10sLK3

Comment: Does `DELETE FROM favorites WHERE uid=whatever AND aid='15LSPf1'` work? It should. If you get problems where the values are being compared as numeric (and deleting everything that's 15 or starts with 15) try adding the `BINARY` keyword: `DELETE FROM favorites WHERE uid=whatever AND BINARY aid='15LSPf1'`.

Comment: This: DELETE FROM favorites WHERE uid=129 AND BINARY aid='13hvTck' won't delete the row unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Try 
$uid = 1;
$aid = 15;

'DELETE FROM favorites WHERE uid="'.$uid.'" AND aid REGEXP "^'.$aid.'"'

Answer (score 0):

Do you ever have leading zeros?

If not then possibly something like this:-

```
DELETE FROM favorites
WHERE CAST( i AS UNSIGNED ) > 0
```

EDIT - to delete a specific record what you originally have would work if the columns are both character format, but not sure why you are using a LIKE. If uid is numeric then:-

```
$uid = 1;
$aid = '15LSPf1';

DELETE FROM favorites WHERE uid=". $uid ." AND aid = '". $aid ."'
```

should workfine

Comment: I am looking to delete ONE specific row where aid = "10sLK3". That's all.